# Gatsby graphql query for GatsbyImage to use a local image from project

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, gatsby-image

I'd just like to use an image using GatsbyImage component.

Normally you do it using `<img src='./img.jpg'/>`.
How is it done with **GatsbyImage**, so i can send an image using props.

Comment: What's the output? What's the error? Do you have `img` data in the `ChildComp`? Is the `useStaticQuery` fetching the proper data?

Comment: `data` is `null`?If so, this is where the issue is... Well, try to provide a Sandbox or similar, it's impossible to guess what's wrong in your structure with dummy data that is not showing the code structure (`data.something` is not present in the query, etc)

Comment: yup, so i added the link to the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use `GatsbyImage` you need to provide extra GraphQL node data that Gatsby infers using its transformers and sharps. To do so, you need to tell Gatsby where those images are, in your case, by setting the following snippet in the `gatsby-config.js`:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
  options: {
    name: `componentImages`,
    path: `${__dirname}/src/components`,
  },
},
```

*Note: you can have many instances of the `gatsby-source-filesystem`*

After starting the `gatsby develop` again to refresh the sources, you will see the node available in the GrahiQL playground (`localhost:8000/___graphql`) where you should test your query but it should look like:

```
  image: file(relativePath: {eq: "free-time.jpg"}) {
    childImageSharp {
      gatsbyImageData
    }
  }
```

Tested in your CodeSandbox and working.

Answer (score -1):

After `npm init gatsby`, `'src/images'` folder is created and this is the basic **root of the relative path** which is set by default in `gatsby.config.js`

```
{
         resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
         options: {
            name: 'images',
            path: `./src/images/`,
         }
}
```

So put your img.jpg to images folder and query by using relative path

```
   const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
  {
     file(relativePath: { eq: "free-time.jpg" }) {
        childImageSharp {
           gatsbyImageData
        }
     }
  }
`);
```

and insert it to GatsbyImage

```
 const img = getImage(data.file);

 <GatsbyImage image={img} />
```